# How do i upload a screencast video to my Blender question?

Tags: support

I would like to include a screencast video in my Blender question, but I do not know how to upload a video.  It is in AVI JPEG format currently.

Thank you!

Comment: Also see http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/404/599